# git : how to perform some operation to some specific submodule

Tags: git, foreach, git-submodules

Git has the `foreach` command to recursively enter each submodule and so some operations. I now want to narrow the scope to some specific ones.

For example, there are 100 submodules inside a git repo. At some point, several of the submodules get dirty, the dirty submodules can show up with `git status -sb`. I only want to execute `git clean` for these dirty submodules.

I can use `git submodule foreach git clean`, however this recursively enter 100 submodules and perform the `git clean`, but most of them are not needed and waste a lot of time.

What I want is some kind of `git submodule foreachdirty`, or at least `git submodule <submoduleName>` to execute command on specific ones. Is there such facility existing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "running a git action in a submodule" is equivalent to :

```
cd path/to/submodule
git action
```

or

```
git -C path/to/submodule action
```

If you have a way to list your dirty submodules,  you can simply run a loop.  For example in bash :

```
# if you have listed them in a file, the command can simply be 'cat dirtylist.txt'
<command to list submodules> | while read submod; do git -C $submod clean -fd; done
```

Comment: Thank you.  `-C` is what I want. I am now having a script identifying the dirty submodules and use '-C' to do operations inside them

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to do the following using git submodule:

`git submodule foreach 'if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then git clean -f; fi'`

or if you know the names of the submodules upfront you can do the following:

`git submodule foreach 'if [ "$name" == "submodule1" ] || [ "$name" == "submodule2" ]; then git clean -f; fi'`

Note: if the submodule is located in a directory within your parent repository then the name of the submodule will include the relative path to it. For example if the submodule path is: ParentRepo/Dir1/Dir2/SubmoduleFolder then then the name of the subrepo would be Dir1/Dir2/SubmoduleFolder.